# Heroku, Gitbash: Cannot find module ‘tslib’

Tags: heroku, git-bash

I’m new to gitbash and I’ve been getting this error for a few weeks now since my first successful attempt at logging in to heroku here via gitbash

I tried reinstalling gitbash and even installing typescript but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a good night of sleep, I found the solution!
I removed the heroku directory in home dir local. See middle of article : https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/672

Comment: This actually worked for me. For others who want a condensed version for windows: Remove `%LOCALAPPDATA%\heroku` then run `heroku login`

Comment: For MacOS via brew, a `brew uninstall --force heroku` and `brew install heroku` does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the 64bit version has a problem.

I uninstalled the 64bit version and I installed 32bit and it worked

Answer (score 2):

I agree and face a similar issue. I have tried to run the install exe both in admin mode and user mode (with admin rights). Same issue. In brief
Heroku is installed correctly 
but then it needs an update
but the update does not finish appropriately (fails to remove node.exe)
I believe the heroku installation became corrupted and once your try to run it, you have the following errors:

heroku-cli: Updating to 6.15.5-1f03166... 10.1 MB/10.1 MB
!    remove C:\Users\Franck\AppData\Local\heroku\client\bin\node.exe: Acces Denied
Error: Cannot find module 'tslib'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as Franck92, after trying a few times to update it went through and it is working now.